# Constrastive vs Counterfactual Explanations

Tags: machine-learning, causality, counterfactuals

Is there any canonical definition for Contrastive vs Counterfactual explanations?

In the literature, I keep reading different versions but I wonder if there are good definitions or illustrative examples. Attempts to get a hold of the two concepts to make indisputable and unambiguous definitions seem to slip between the fingers.

What I have found so far?

- [T. Miller, Contrastive explanation: A structural-model approach (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03163)
- S. Wachter, B. Mittelstadt, and C. Russell, Counterfactual explanations without opening the black box: Automated decisions and the GDPR (2017), Harv. JL & Tech., 31:841.
- [Counterfactual vs Contrastive Explanations in Artificial Intelligence](https://towardsdatascience.com/counterfactual-vs-contrastive-explanations-in-artificial-intelligence-e67a9cfc7e4e)

Comment: Crossposted with no answers in: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/95122/constrastive-vs-counterfactual-explanations

Comment: Please [do not crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I'd say your question's probably better suited to this site than to the Data Science site. From their help pages: "Questions are most appropriate here [Data Science S.E.] if they are concerned with putting statistical concepts into practice, focus on implementation and (business) processes. Compared with statistics, data science is concerned with implementing whole analytical systems that can ingest (mainly large and diverse) data sets and estimate quantities of interest by incorporating advances from multiple fields."